# WSAGetLastError with unknown error code

Tags: error-handling, dns, gethostbyname

I am using WSAGetLastError function to retrieve failure details when using getHostByName function. But the error code returned by the function is 0042124C is not available in the documentation. Am I receiving the error code in some other format or am I using the function in a faulty way?

Thanks.

PS. Code segment below

```
// DNS Hostname.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DNS Hostname.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// The one and only application object

CWinApp theApp;

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
    if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        cerr << _T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed") << endl;
        nRetCode = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        WORD wVersionRequested;
        WSADATA wsaData;
        int err;
        wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

        err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);


        HOSTENT* pHostDetails = NULL;
        pHostDetails = gethostbyname("IE10-FLYFB1S");

        if(pHostDetails)
        {
            int nList = 0;
            CString sAddressString;
            CString sSQLAddress;
            CString sSQLMachine;
            unsigned long addr;

            while ( pHostDetails->h_addr_list[nList] )
            {
                addr = (*(u_long FAR *) pHostDetails->h_addr_list[nList]);

                sAddressString.Format(_T("%d.%d.%d.%d"),(addr & 255),((addr >> 8) & 255),((addr >> 16) & 255),((addr >> 24) & 255));

                sSQLAddress.Format(_T(" OR Machine = '%s' "),sAddressString);
                sSQLMachine += sSQLAddress;

                nList++;
            }
            cout << sSQLMachine << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            int error = WSAGetLastError();
            cout << error << endl;
        }
    }

    WSACleanup();

    return nRetCode;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

getHostByName is deprecated, use getaddrinfo instead.

Comment: Doesn't explain the phenomena in any way.